# How to do a subquery on a select statement to show something like this

Tags: sql

I joined bunch of tables to get diagnosis for some people. I added a filter that only catches certain people who has certain diagnosis. In my example below, I separated those who have fever.

[image]

[image]

Here, Patient with ID 1 has 4 diagnosis and Patient with ID 2 has 3 diagnosis. They both have fever along with other problems.

Now I want show the other problem these folks have along with the fever diagnosis like this below example.

[image]

Is there any way I can group by Patient ID and show all of their diagnosis on one row? Like having a subquery on a select statement. I am not good with SQL so an example code would be very helpful.

Comment: Do it on application side, it makes little sense doing it on SQL side

Comment: use group_concat for comma separated values.

Answer (score 1):

You can group_concat

```
SELECT NAME, DateOfBirth, ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Diagnosis)
FROM <your_table>
GROUP BY NAME, DateOfBirth, ID
```

Comment: I get this error saying " 'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name "

Comment: @RingtailLemur . . . Then you are not using MySQL and your question is mistagged.

Comment: @Ringtail Lemur please check your database.